# chartjs: Not rendering when using mobile

Tags: javascript, mobile, chart.js

I am using the chartsJS library(2.4) to create doughnut chart. It work perfect if I use  a regular computer. But if try to access it using a mobile device the chart does not render at all. What am I doing wrong? The code is below

```
<script>
    var data = {
        labels: [
            "Team 1",
            "Team 2",
        ],
        datasets: [
            {
                data: [<?=$team1_pct?>, <?=$team2_pct?>],
                backgroundColor: [
                    "#14c9ea",
                    "#0f1e2d",
                ],
                hoverBackgroundColor: [
                    "#14c9ea",
                    "#0f1e2d",
                ]
            }]
    };
    var canvas=document.getElementById("myChart");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    var myDoughnutChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'doughnut',
        data: data,
        options:{ responsive: true,
            title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'Head to Head',
            },
        cutoutPercentage: 60,
            animation: {
                onComplete: function (animation) {
                    var canvas = document.getElementById("myChart");
                    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                    ctx.font = "36px verdana";
                    ctx.fillText("VS", 110, 142);
                }
            }
        },

    });

</script>
```

thank you.

Comment: this thread https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/713 might help you

Comment: @VinodLouis - thank you for the tip but it didn't work. I am not sure what could be wrong. Any other idea? thanks.

Comment: do you have an url which works on desktop and not in mobile try in mobile with landscape mode does it load?

Comment: It does not load on landscape mode either. The url is not accessible for outside yet.